# Show that there are positive real numbers $\{ \lambda_i \}$ such that $\sum_i \lambda_i f_i$ is a smooth function.

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

$f_i$ are smooth functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\operatorname{supp} f_i$ compact. Show that there are positive real numbers $\{ \lambda_i \}$ s.t. $\sum_i \lambda_i f_i$ is a smooth function.

I have tried to consider the partitions of unity when I see $\{\mathbb{R}^n-\operatorname{supp}f_i\}$ as an open covering of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I am stuck. What I want to know most is how to find these positive real numbers $\{ \lambda_i \}$? Do they have any special meaning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there something missing? You can choose all $\lambda_i=1$, or any other positive values.

Comment: @Martin you can't choose all $\lambda_i=1$ because this doesn't ensure convergence, by example if there are infinitely many $f_i$ that share some compact support

Comment: Then what about $\lambda_i = \frac{1}{i^2}\Vert f_i \Vert_\infty $ ?

Comment: @MartinR: that won't work if $\||f_i\|_\infty \ge i^2$for all $i$, but it is easy to fix. Why don't you write it up as an answer?

Comment: ... I meant $\lambda_i = \dfrac{1}{i^2 \cdot \Vert f_i \Vert_\infty}$. But it would be good to know if $i \in \Bbb N$ or if the indices are from an arbitrary set.

Comment: Presumably the indexes $i$ here range over $\Bbb{N}$. If there are uncountably many $f_i$, this can't be done.

Comment: @Rob if they will be uncountable many $f_i$ then such $\lambda_i$ doesn't exists, that is, there is no positive $\lambda_i$ that can make the unordered sum $\sum_i \lambda_i f_i$ convergent in the general case (that is, by example when uncountable many $f_i$ share some compact support and are ll bounded below by some positive constant)

Comment: @Masacroso: that's why I was asking the OP to clarify the question.

Comment: Yeah, I think it should be countable @Rob